# "A few years later" vs "A few Years from now"

Tags: time-words

May I know for the following two sentences:

"A few years later" vs "A few years from now"

which is grammatical?

Comment: Both are fine. They are used for different contexts, though, so I would not compare the two side-by-side. Also, they are only phrases, not sentences, just FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two phrases would generally be used in different contexts:

> > A few years later.....

implies something that happened some years after a specified time or event, as in:

> > He graduated in 2010; a few years later he had founded his own company.

That's to say: a few years after his graduation in 2010

But:

> > A few years from now ....

means in a few years from the present - in a few years' time!

> > A few years from now I shall have completed my studies.